# How to add subplot title to 3D subplot in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am plotting a images with 4 subplots, e.g. using the following code.
How can I add title to each subplot?

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools

import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-5, 80, 10)
y = np.linspace(-5, 60, 10)
xGrid, yGrid = np.meshgrid(y, x)
z = xGrid ** 3 + yGrid ** 3

scene = dict(
    xaxis=dict(
        gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        showbackground=True,
        backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        showbackground=True,
        backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
    ),
    zaxis=dict(
        gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        showbackground=True,
        backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
    )
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2,
                        specs=[[{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}],
                                [{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}]])

# adding surfaces to subplots.
fig.append_trace(dict(type='surface', x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale='Viridis',
                    scene='scene1', showscale=False), 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(dict(type='surface', x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale='RdBu',
                    scene='scene2', showscale=False), 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(dict(type='surface', x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale='YlOrRd',
                    scene='scene3', showscale=False), 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(dict(type='surface', x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale='YlGnBu',
                    scene='scene4', showscale=False), 2, 2)

fig['layout'].update(title='subplots with different colorscales',
                    height=800, width=800)
fig['layout']['scene1'].update(scene)
fig['layout']['scene2'].update(scene)
fig['layout']['scene3'].update(scene)
fig['layout']['scene4'].update(scene)

py.plot(fig, filename='multiple_plots.html')
```

I tried to replace

```
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, specs=[[{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': 
True}], [{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}]])
```

with the following

```
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles= ('Plot1','Plot2','Plot3','Plot4'),specs=[[{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}],[{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}]])
```

It gives me the following error

---

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     33 fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2,subplot_titles= ('p1','p2','p3','p4'),
     34                           specs=[[{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}],
---> 35                                  [{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}]])
     36 
     37 # adding surfaces to subplots.

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py in make_subplots(rows, cols, shared_xaxes, shared_yaxes, start_cell, print_grid, **kwargs)
   1373             pass
   1374         else:
-> 1375             plot_titles.append({'y': subtitle_pos_y[index],
   1376                                 'xref': 'paper',
   1377                                 'x': subtitle_pos_x[index],

IndexError: list index out of range

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me. [Here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/plotly/tools.py#L1082-L1104) it seems like `list_of_domains` is never appended to for the 3d plots. When I added the kwarg `shared_xaxes=True` it works for me.

```
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2,
                    specs=[[{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}],
                            [{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}]],
                    subplot_titles=('a','b','c','d'), shared_xaxes=True)
```

[image]

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. But if it is a bug. I will just leave it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Are you sure? Because it works perfect if I paste into your code. I'm using `python 3.5` and `plotly 3.2.1`